# Unable to install software center

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I could not see the software center on my ubuntu so I referred to this answer and then I saw broken packages so I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but it said `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`. When I tried to install software center with command below the error pops up.

```
root@gautam-Inspiron-3542:~# sudo apt install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-center : Depends: software-center-aptdaemon-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-gi but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: oneconf (>= 0.2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: sessioninstaller but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help on solving this is really appreciated.

Comment: Please stop! Software center **should** be there but if it needs to be reinstalled the package is `ubuntu-software`. The one you were trying to install is the old app that no longer works.

Comment: @MichaelBay I created a new Ubuntu guest OS in VirtualBox yesterday and installed software-center in it with `apt` and it installed a few additional packages along with it but it worked just fine. I like Ubuntu Software Center because it has the expandable list feature that makes it easier to search for packages which contain a specific string in their package names.